# Update the user table's field if url like login/xyzcode

Tags: php, laravel

I am checking the user's email is valid or not, so I am sending email to user on add user.so when user go to inbox and click the url in the email will redirect them to my laravel web app.And when I got the url like login/code I want to check the code is match and then set true to email_verified and login the user.I stuck here thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you know what you want to do, all you need to do is go and code it.

Comment: giving a brief idea : create a token,store it against user,provide that token in the url and when user clicks on the url,find the user with that token and set email_verified for that user

Comment: ya but want to check that verified_email using the default logincontroller.

Comment: Great, so what have you done so far to try and make this happen?

Comment: are u asking about where to check "verified_email" == 1  in login function?

Comment: yes because in my logincontroller i have only this much code use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/sites';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }       and i am also confuse about the url because when i sendingthe token with my login/token url it will not cal the controller so from where i can set that url for login in my route i don't have the route for login. only Auth::routes(); is there for login.